# stats on *total* cost of high-efficiency boiler?

Tags: boiler, maintenance, cost-effective

Not trying to start a subjective debate here, just looking for some objective statistics.

I get that high-efficiency boilers are *much* more efficient, and will save big bucks over their lifetime in terms of fuel saved.  I get that they're more complicated and cost more.  (I get that the manufacturers can also charge more based on the expected fuel savings.)

But everybody I know who has one is paying through the nose for maintenance.  It seems (perhaps this is a biased opinion) that the things are always breaking down, and when they do the replacement parts are always (a) hideously expensive and (b) on backorder.

Is there any data on this?  I'm curious if anyone has done any studies on the total cost of ownership of a high-efficiency boiler, factoring in not only the initial cost and the fuel saved, but also a realistic assessment of the actual maintenance costs.

Comment: I'm certain that the manufacturers have and that their reports come back positively _glowing_! ;) Good question.

Comment: While this is a very interesting subject, it doesn't really follow the guidelines for this DIY site. It should be in a discussion group.

Comment: If you are replacing a fairly new boiler (<7 years old) then the payback will take some time...

Comment: Could you provide the type of boiler you are referring to? I ask because some call the system I call a water heater for cleaning & bathing etc a boiler  but what I call a boiler is used as a heater or primarily a heat source even though in some cases they can be the same exact thing but plumbed differently.

Comment: @EdBeal I'm thinking of the ones that are conventionally used for forced hot water heating, or optionally (perhaps with an additional heat exchanger) for domestic hot water. (And yes, the terminology sucks, because different people use the terms differently, and the thing you and I call a "boiler" doesn't actually boil water.)